# How/where do I use ACM CCS categorization in my document?

Tags: positioning, acm

I'm writing a conference for an ACM workshop. I've [picked out some CCS concepts](http://dl.acm.org/ccs/ccs.cfm?) relevant to my article, and I have the "XMLish" and "LaTeXish" code for them - but I'm not sure where in my TeX file I'm supposed to put it (i.e. where I should place the `\printccsdesc` command). Enlighten me?

Answer (score 2):

Put the code anywhere before `\maketitle`.  Do not use the command `\printccsdesc`

For example,

```
\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010553.10010562</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Embedded systems</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010575.10010755</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Redundancy</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>300</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010553.10010554</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Robotics</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>100</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10003033.10003083.10003095</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Networks~Network reliability</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>100</concept_significance>
 </concept>
</ccs2012>  
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Computer systems organization~Embedded systems}
\ccsdesc[300]{Computer systems organization~Redundancy}
\ccsdesc{Computer systems organization~Robotics}
\ccsdesc[100]{Networks~Network reliability}

%
% End generated code
%


\maketitle
```

Comment: Does the `\begin{CCXML}` go in the document body, or in the preamble?

Comment: in the body, as in the samples in the documentation.

Comment: I get "Enviroment CCSXML undefined." Any ideas on what I can do to solve this? I'm not using the acmart document class since I'm supposed to use a different one for the conference I'm submitting.

Comment: `CCSXML` is a feature of `acmart`.  Other classes do not support it